# Can't understand big-O of a nested loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am having problem understanding the answer to the following question about analyzing two algorithms below.

```
for (int i = n ; i >= 1; i = i/2) {
   for ( int j = 1; j <= n ; j++) {
     //do something                
   }
}
```

The algorithm above has complexity of O(n) according to the answers. Shouldn't it be lower since the outer loop always halves the amount we have to go through. I thought that it should be something along the lines of O(n/2 * )?

```
for ( int j = 1; j <= n ; j++ ) {
    for ( int i = n ; i >= j ; i = i / 2 ) {
       //do something 
    }
}
```

This one is O(n log n) if I am correct?

Comment: Please look at my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first iteration will execute `n` steps, the second will execute `n/2`, the third will execute `n/4`, and so on.

If you compute the sum of `n/(2^i)` for `i=0..log n` you will get roughly `2n` and that is why it is `O(n)`.

If you take `n` out of the summation and sum only the `1/(2^i)` part, you will get `2`. Take a look at an example:

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ... = 1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125 + 0.0625 + ... = 2
```

Each next element is twice smaller, therefore the sum will never exceed `2`.

You are right with the second nested loop example - it is `O(n log n)`.

**EDIT:**

After the comment from ringø I re-read the question and in fact the algorithm is different from what I understood. ringø is right, the algorithm as described in the question is `O(n log n)`. However, judging from the context I think that the OP meant an algorithm where the inner loop is tied to `i` and not `n`.

This answer relates to the following algorithm:

```
for (int i = n ; i >= 1; i = i/2) {
   for ( int j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
     //do something                
   }
}
```

Comment: What? This is wrong. The first algorithm is `O(n log n)`!

Comment: So, *judging from the context* you answer to a different question, boldly mark my answer as *wrong* misleading the OP to  accept your answer. How fair is that?

Comment: @ringø, the op has written: "the outer loop always halves the amount we have to go through". We can only state that the op either made an error in the code, or in that sentence. I've assumed the former. Judging from that the op has accepted my answer which explicitly assumes that the inner loop is tied to `i` and not `n`, I have correctly understood the intentions of OP. I'm sorry for you, because there is no fault in your answer, we just took different interpretations to a misleading question. The op should clarify what he really meant. Is there an error in the code or in the description.

Comment: @ringø More precisely, I didn't even notice in the begining that the loop is tied to `n`. Only upon your comment I realized that, and made an edit, but the answer was already accepted. Now it only remains to wait for op to say something, if he/she will ever do.

Comment: @ciamej yep your edit is correct, I somehow copied the algorithm wrong from the exercise or something, here is the original code from the exercise http://puu.sh/lQeKL/728667b1e4.png